# Error with php 7.3.10 in windows syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php, windows, symfony, xampp, php-7.3

when installing in windows through xampp an application in Symfony 4 returns me the following error when executing bin/console

> syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\labels\vendor\ocramius\proxy-manager\src\ProxyManager\Configuration.php:29

Line 29 in is "protected ?string `$proxiesTargetDir`;"

appears to be a support problem for nullable types but the PHP version is >7.1

---

```
php -v
PHP 7.3.10 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2019 11:59:22) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.10, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Add a `phpinfo()` call to the xamp server to make sure it is actually using the instance of PHP you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using version 2.4 or higher of the `ocramius/proxy-manager` package which requires PHP 7.4+. Make sure to only install packages that are compatible with the PHP version that you are running. More specifically do not run `composer update` with the `--ignore-platform-reqs` option.